# Prove Non-Homogeneous Farkas' Lemma

Tags: optimization, solution-verification, convex-analysis, alternative-proof, karush-kuhn-tucker

> Prove Non-Homogeneous Farkas' Lemma
> Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m \times n},c\in\mathbb{R}^{n},b\in\mathbb{R}^{m},d\in\mathbb{R},$
> Suppose that there exist $y\geq0$ such that $A^Ty=c$ Prove that excatly one of the following is feasible:
> A.$Ax\leq b,c^Tx>d$
> B. $A^Ty=c,b^Ty<d,y\geq0$

My attempt is the following.
Assume that B holds and we'll show that A doesn't.
$Ax\leq b\iff y^tAx\leq y^tb\iff (A^Ty)^Tx\leq d\iff c^Tx\leq d$ and A doesn't hold.

I'm not sure about this part of my proof
Assume that B doesn't holds and we'll show that A is feasible.
If B doesn't holds then $A^Ty=c,b^Ty=d$ doesn't holds aswell. Setting $\tilde{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
A^T\\b^T
\end{pmatrix},\tilde{c}=\begin{pmatrix}
c\\d
\end{pmatrix}$ Now from the homog. Farkas' Lemma we know that $\tilde{A}\tilde{x}\leq 0,\tilde{c}>0\iff Ax+x_{n+1}b\leq0,c^Tx+dx_{n+1}>0$ setting $x_{n+1}=-1$ we get $Ax\leq b,c^T>d$ as desired.\

Comment: Could you reformat your attempt? It is not readable. You also make some implicit assumptions, for example in the first doublearrow you assume $y \geq 0$.

Comment: I assumed that B holds and therefore $y\geq0$

Comment: what is the argument behind "If B doesn't hold then $A^Ty=c,b^Ty=d$ doesn't hold either"?

Comment: @LinAlg I think the important part is that $b^Ty=d$ cannot hold, and then you can use the homogeneous Farkas lemma, i.e. denote $\tilde{A} := (A, b)$ and $\tilde{c} := (c, d)^T$. So $\tilde{A}^Ty = (A^Ty, b^Ty)^T = (c, b^Ty)^T \neq (c, d)^T$. The question is why can we later assume that $x_{n+1}=-1$?

Comment: @MaverickMeerkat The only reason I did it because it finished the question..

Answer (score 1):

If this comes from the book *Introduction to Nonlinear Optimization* by Amir Beck, then the question is Exercise 10.2.

Here is a method that uses Gordan's alternative theorem mentioned in the book.

To show that the system $A$'s infeasibility implies the feasibility of the system $B$, we note that the system $A$
$$
\begin{cases}
    A \mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{b}\\
     \mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{x} > d  \\
\end{cases}
$$

is feasible if and only if the following system is feasible

$$
\begin{cases}
    A \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b} - s \mathbf{e} <\mathbf{0} \\
    -\mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{x} + d < 0 \\
    -s < 0
\end{cases}
$$

where $\mathbf{e} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is a vector of all ones and $s$ is a positive real number. Thus, defining matrix $\tilde{A}$ as:

$$
\tilde{A} = \begin{pmatrix}
    A & -\mathbf{b}-s\mathbf{e} \\
    -\mathbf{c}^T & d
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and vector $\tilde{\mathbf{x}}$ as $\tilde{\mathbf{x}} = \begin{pmatrix}
    \mathbf{x} \\
    1
\end{pmatrix}$, we have obtained a new system that is equivalent to $A$:
$$
\tilde{A} \tilde{\mathbf{x}} < \mathbf{0}
$$

By Gordon's alternative theorem, we know that the system $\tilde{A} \tilde{\mathbf{x}} < 0$ is infeasible if and only if the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
    \tilde{\mathbf{p}} \neq \mathbf{0} \\
    \tilde{A}^T \tilde{\mathbf{p}} = \mathbf{0} \\
    \tilde{\mathbf{p}} \geq \mathbf{0}
\end{cases}
$$

is feasible.

To see that the system above is equivalent to $B$, we note that we can write:

$$
\tilde{A}^T \tilde{\mathbf{p}} = \begin{pmatrix}
    A & -\mathbf{b}-s\mathbf{e} \\
    -\mathbf{c}^T & d
\end{pmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix}
    \mathbf{p} \\
    q
\end{pmatrix} = \mathbf{0}
$$

for some non-negative real number $q$. Thus, we have:
$$
\begin{cases}
    A^T \mathbf{p} = \mathbf{c} q  \\
    \mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{p} = dq - s \mathbf{e}^T \mathbf{p}  \\
\end{cases}
$$

When $q = 0$, we have already established the equivalence.

If $q > 0$, we can write $\mathbf{y}=(\frac{1}{q})\mathbf{p} \geq \mathbf{0}$:

$$
\begin{cases}
    A^T \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{c} \\
    \mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{y} = d - s \mathbf{e}^T \mathbf{y} \leq d\\
\end{cases}
$$

as $s>0, \mathbf{e}^T \mathbf{y} \geq 0$, so we have established the equivalence with system $B$.

For alternative proof, refer to the book Nonlinear Programming by O. L. Mangasarian [(link)](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971255).